# Selenium webdriver.back() not working in Firefox?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, firefox

I'm clicking links on a main page, scraping the info, going back using `driver.back()`, and then getting an error where it says it can't find the next element on the page because it hasn't gone back at all.  I added `driver.implicitly_wait(2)` after the back command, and still not having any success.

Has anyone had this same problem and know a workaround?  I can always just do `driver.get(original_url)`, so I'd just like to know if I'm doing something wrong.

Here is the error if it is helpful, it's basically just telling us that the element was unable to be found due to the page not going back:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Bridge (Ruby)"}
Stacktrace:
    at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_ (file:///var/folders/yq/27hmdjbx4s38vfgwsc8htm1stw8y2j/T/tmpvmh9pbdv/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10723)
    at fxdriver.Timer.prototype.setTimeout/<.notify (file:///var/folders/yq/27hmdjbx4s38vfgwsc8htm1stw8y2j/T/tmpvmh9pbdv/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:623)
```

Comment: Which driver are you using ? (Firefox, chrome, .. ?)

Comment: Sorry, I guess that's kind of important;)  I added Firefox to the title.

Comment: Probably... at least I can tell you that I don't encounter this behavior using the Chrome driver in selenium with python 3 (I will update for Firefox but it seems that I can't make Firefox driver work at all for now..)

Comment: Okay I'll give Chrome a try

Comment: I just tested with firefox and it seems to work too. Maybe you can post the complete error message you obtained ?

Comment: Added error message.  And confirmed it works with Chrome on a Mac.

Comment: So it seems you don't get any Exception from `driver.back()` but only from the next selection you are trying to do.. I don't really have idea if it works on another platform. Good luck anyway!

Comment: Is your browser actually going BACK to the main page when you want it to ? Try to increase your timeout to 10 seconds or more. If that helps, then you might have a timing problem. And please avoid implicit waits.